# Sharing a method between NSViewController and NSTableViewDelegate

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an architectural problem with cocoa framework.

So the thing is that in my app I have a **MasterView** that contains 2 subviews:

- **RecentFilesTableView** which contains files recently used by user. User will select file by double click.
- **OtherFileView** with a button ‘Open another file’ which invokes NSOpenPanel.

Both views will call at the end method: openFileWithUrl(url: NSURL)

So the question is: what is the best (the most apple) way to archive this ?

## Solution 1

I place method **openFileWithUrl(url: NSURL)** in **MasterViewConroller**

My **RecentFilesTableDelegate** will have reference to **MasterViewConroller** and will call the method.

I place the controller for **OtherFileView** in **MasterViewConroller**.

Cons: Reference hell (this class references this, which references this and so on..).

## Solution 2

I will use **MasterViewConroller** as a really *master* controller that will react on both double click in ‘recent table’ and click on ‘Open another file’ button.

I would have to somehow get the selected file from **RecentFilesTableView**. I have not seen an method for doing this (ofc. I can cast the tableView.dataSource() to my class. But I believe that the clean design does not involve such casting).

Cons: One class to rule them all.

## Solution 3

As I can't create a superclass for both RecentTableDelegate and MasterViewController I can use Swift extensions to add a opening method to them. But thats not very OOP.

So what's the pattern in Apple world of doing such things?

Comment: Please do not abuse tags.  Nothing about this question has anything to do with Swift, Objective-C, and certainly not iOS.

Comment: Did you consider bindings or the first responder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to avoid repetitions of the implementation of `openFileWithUrl(url: NSURL)`, you can create a separate class for these types of operations such as `NetworkManager`. This solution is along the lines of Apple's `NSFileManager`. When you need to perform that operation, create an instance of that class and call the function.

Comment: How will this manager put the contents of the file in OtherFileView?

Comment: Thanks for help Daniel. I just thought that there may be some design pattern that I should follow for this kind of operation. And for your question Willeke: Actually I don't need to have an reference to this object in OtherFileView. So problem solved.

Comment: @MailSO It's great that you are thinking about such things. I'm glad it's solved.